Inverse differencing in continuous time
I want to fit a continuous time ARMA (CARMA) model to traffic data $T_t$. After removing trend and seasonality I need first order differencing to obtain stationarity. Then I fit a CARMA model (yuima package in R) to the data. Let $C_t$ be the fitted model.
Question:
In order to obtain forecasts, I need inverse differencing of the model. Can i just integrate over $C_t$? So if I define $Y_t :dY_t=C_t$ so $Y_t = \int_0^t C_sds $.
Assuming that $b_t$ is the trend and seasonal component, we would have $T_t = b_t + Y_t$
Thanks:)

How is this related to quantitative finance? If it is not, consider posting it on Mathematics Stack Exchange instead.

This is used to obtain option prices where travel time is the underlying asset.

OK, that makes sense.
